# Why is Math.abs() returning 25 and saying no explicit return value?

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused about the math.abs() function. I need to debug this code but I somehow can't find the problem. It always says "no explicit return value" when I try to println() the result.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(i - 25) + Math.abs(j - 25) > 25) {
                    System.out.println(" ");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("+");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

I expect the program to output " " when the result of math.abs() is higher than 25 and "+" when it's lower than 25.

Comment: Exactly -- I don't see an obvious respect in which the output (as can be seen at https://ideone.com/FWrwK2) is wrong. A question needs to be explicit enough that readers actually know *what the problem they're being asked to help with* is; that is, exactly what output you expect, and what you're getting instead. (It also helps to loop over the smallest possible range for which you get unexpected/"wrong" output, just to make it easier to talk about).

Comment: We're given the task to identify the problem in this code. I think the errors occurs when the program compares the math.abs() value with > 25.

Comment: What errors? Follow the ideone.com link above to see your code running in an online interpreter; it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: BTW the first two `println`s should be `print` - without newline. That the void method main has no return value is probably what the error conveys, so probably the debugging was not correct. Use breakpoints or single step - if needed.

Comment: If you're talking about the "no explicit return value" *warning*, it's just that, a warning, and it's moot, because you're declaring your value as `void`. If you declared it as an `int`, though, you'd be expected to do something like `return 0`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Good observation, finding that (first) "problem". I included it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806044/5221149).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [comment by Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805447/why-is-math-abs-returning-25-and-saying-no-explicit-return-value#comment103891266_58805447) identified the *first* "problem":

> the first two `println`s should be `print` - without newline.

When you change that, the output becomes:

```
                         +                        
                        +++                       
                       +++++                      
                      +++++++                     
                     +++++++++                    
                    +++++++++++                   
                   +++++++++++++                  
                  +++++++++++++++                 
                 +++++++++++++++++                
                +++++++++++++++++++               
               +++++++++++++++++++++              
              +++++++++++++++++++++++             
             +++++++++++++++++++++++++            
            +++++++++++++++++++++++++++           
           +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++          
          +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++         
         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        
        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       
       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++      
      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     
     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     
       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++      
        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       
         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        
          +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++         
           +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++          
            +++++++++++++++++++++++++++           
             +++++++++++++++++++++++++            
              +++++++++++++++++++++++             
               +++++++++++++++++++++              
                +++++++++++++++++++               
                 +++++++++++++++++                
                  +++++++++++++++                 
                   +++++++++++++                  
                    +++++++++++                   
                     +++++++++                    
                      +++++++                     
                       +++++                      
                        +++
```

The second "problem" is that the output is missing a single `+` on the right and on the bottom.

I'll leave it to you to figure that one out. It is after all *your* assignment, not ours.

Comment: One more question, how did you get to that conclusion by using the debugger? I don't think i would've identified the problem anytime soon :O

Comment: @zer0-day I didn't use a debugger. I ran the code, or rather clicked on the [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/FWrwK2) link provided by Charles Duffy, and saw a lot of blank lines, and thought "That can't be right", so I looked at the code and saw the `println` calls and the comment by Joop Eggen, so I simply changed the two `println` to `print` and got the output you see in this answer. I looked at the pattern of the output and thought again "That can't be right", and then wrote the answer to alert you to it. In short, I observed the output of the program, and applied common sense.